# Search algorithm for a string against a list of string tags

Tags: string, algorithm, search, tags, string-comparison

I am currently trying to implement a searching algorithm where the user will enter a string query that will be compared to an object containing a list of string "tags", or just single word strings. I want the result to be the list of the objects sorting by the list that had the best match to this query.

My current implementation is using Levenshtein Distance on each tag with the query, adding that to a total, and dividing by the number of tags. I'm imaging a lot of downsides to this approach however and was wondering if there is a more common way to approach this.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55804367/10396

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar. 
[How to extract keywords (tags) from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339290/how-to-extract-keywords-tags-from-text)

How long is your query ???

For small query text you can visit

https://towardsdatascience.com/extracting-keywords-from-short-text-fce39157166b

I don't think Levenshtein Distance is very effective way of generating token. It is based on the string miss matched , however from query you would want to know the keyword which represents the intent of your query and then check from your tags list , which suits it perfect .

You can use many library available such as nltk , apache open nlp etc for your purpose. They directly generates token .

This might help you. 
[How to extract keywords (tags) from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339290/how-to-extract-keywords-tags-from-text)